# About the Cartan's moving frame method

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am learning Cartan's moving frame from chapter 6 of S.S. Chern's book "Lectures on differential geometry" ([Google books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Mvk7DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Suppose the moving frame in $E^N$ is denoted by $(p;e_1,\cdots,e_N)$, then we can apply an infinitesimal motion on $(p;e_1,\cdots,e_N)$ to get the equation (3.22) on p.202 Chern's book:
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{split}
dp=\displaystyle{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{N}\omega^{\alpha}e_{\alpha}}\\
de_{\alpha}=\displaystyle{\sum_{\beta=1}^{N}\omega^{\beta}_{\alpha}e_{\beta}}
\end{split} \right.
\end{equation}
where the $\omega^{\alpha}$ and $\omega^{\beta}_{\alpha}$ are one forms. In my understanding, the $e_{\alpha}$'s  are understood as $\mathbb{R}^N$ valued **functions** (of some $N$ variables $(u_1,\cdots,u_N)$) since we can do the operator $d$ to them. In other words, the $e_{\alpha}$'s **are not really vector fields** in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (by vector field I mean a **contravariant 1-tensor field**) since we can't do the $d$ operator to a vector field. However, Chern's book treat the $e_{\alpha}$'s as vector fields and it takes the one forms $\omega^{\beta}_{\alpha}$ as connection 1-form as the Levi-Civita connection for $\mathbb{R}^N$ and do covariant derivative $D$ to $e_{\alpha}$ (this is (3.38) on p.207 Chern's book):
$$
De_{\alpha}=\omega_{\alpha}^{\beta}e_{\beta}
$$
(Here, I take $m=N$ in Chern's book). So my question is why we can treat the $e_{\alpha}$ as contravariant fileds in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and do the $d$ operator to them? Why the one forms $\omega_{\alpha}^{\beta}$ (gotten from the equation for the moving frame) are exactly the **connection 1-forms** for the Levi-Civita connection on $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: You might consider reading the recent book of Jeanne Clelland, From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames. It has more information on this question and is easier to read and more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make sense of this is to view $p, e_1, \dots, e_N$ as functions on the orthonormal frame bundle of $\mathbb{R}^N$, which is naturally isomorphic to the group of rigid motions, where there is a right action of the group $O(N)$ of rotations, which fixes the point $p$ and rotates the frame and $\mathbb R^N$ is the set of left cosets with respect to this action. The $1$-forms are now well defined on the frame bundle and are in fact the left invariant $1$-forms (also known as the Maurer-Cartan forms) on the group. The equations satisfied by these 1-forms are the Maurer-Cartan equations for the group of rigid motions.

If you're familiar with Lie groups and homogeneous spaces, a nice exposition of this is in a paper of Griffiths: *On Cartan's method of Lie groups and moving frames as applied to uniqueness and existence questions in differential geometry,* 
Duke Math. J. 41 (1974), 775–814.

Comment: I have read Griffiths' paper. I think the point is that we treat $\mathbb{R}^N$ as the quotient space of the Lie group $E(N)$ (which is isomorphic to the frame bundle) under the action of $O(N)$ so that the ambient space (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^N$) of the functions $\psi:\,E(N)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ (p 783 of Griffiths paper) can be contanined in $E(N)$ so that the equation $d\psi(F)=\displaystyle{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{N}}\psi_{\alpha}(F)e_{\alpha}$ makes sense. Am I right?

Comment: Can you expain how to show that the forms $\psi_{\alpha}$ in  $d\psi(F)=\displaystyle{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{N}}\psi_{\alpha}(F)e_{\alpha}$ are left invariant on $E(N)$ on p.783 of Griffiths's paper ? and can you recommand some reference for Lie groups and homogeneous space and the principal bundles (concerning this problem)?

Comment: @JDoe, I think Ben McKay's recommendation of Jeanne Clelland's book is a good one.

Comment: @DeaneYang With respect to the first comment I think (but I want to be confirmed) that the point is not that $\mathbb{R}^N$ "is contained" in $E(N)$, but that the elements of $E(N)$ can be "characterized" by $(N+1)$-uples of elements of $\mathbb{R}^N$: $(p,e_1,...)$. Together with the fact that $T_pR^N=R^N$. But then I have a question: this is not a valid construction for every Lie group, or it is?

Comment: @J.Doe I explain a bit more: I know that MC-form is a general construction for any Lie group. But the general way we construct them in any Lie group (fixing a basis of left invariant vector fields) is not what is done in Griffiths or Clelland. Is this particular construction only valid in a few situations?

Comment: @AntonioJPan, it is important to note that points are not contained in $E(N)$. Instead, there is a map from the frame bundle to the space of points. This construction works if there is a frame bundle over a space and a Lie group that acts faithfully and transitively on the frame bundle.

Comment: @DeaneYang Ok with respect to the no inclusion of points. WRT the generality of the construction: if the space is a homogeneous space $X=G/H$ then $G$ is a frame bundle for $X$ and $G$ itself acts faithfully and transitively on it (isn't it?). But this construction of Griffiths or Clelland doen't have to work here, we only can write the MC form "in abstract". I guess you have to require something else (for example $G=\mathbb{R}^n \rtimes H$ and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{R}^n \oplus \mathfrak{h}$?)

Comment: @DeaneYang I realize this is difficult to deal with in comments, so I have created a new question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432563/maurer-cartan-form-and-levi-civita-connection